# woocommerce first click slow-subsequent clicks are fast

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have redone my woocommerce website from scratch and with new domain name now hotrange.co.uk.I now use supercache ,hypercache and maxcdn with dedicated server with good specs .I have observed my website from scratch when i was uploading csv feeds and found that it is very fast till the times my products up loaded were up to 2000,the moment it crossed this limit the site started getting slow. Now the issues i am facing after uploading 20k products are as follows.

1-site is slow for login customers.

2-site is slow for unlogged customers but for first click only,the moment they reclick same category or product it opens in mili seconds.It seems cache issue but why first time cache pages are not served.

I have put my memory limit to 1024 because it exhausts memory limit quickly if i upload csv file with memory limit of 128 etc.My loading is over so i can always bring it down if it is harmful but it is just for your info. Mainly large database seems issue but it should not be for resources i am using and 20k products are not huge i suppose but it is the cause of slow loading and any help will be appreciated please as it is my sixth month ever since i am fighting with this site's speed and not reaching any where.

Comment: "It seems cache issue but why first time cache pages are not served." Because its browser caching, not server caching.

Comment: What is solution please as i am not expert.Please write in simple language what action i need to take from server or CSN  side or in supercache if any change is required.Shall be much obliged.